# Prove $\frac{1}{2} \|y-x\|^2$ is a strongly convex function

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Get stuck in proving $f(y)=\frac{1}{2} {||y-x||}^2$ is strongly convex function (Assume $x$ is fixed).

My Proof:
$y_1$, $y_2$ are two variables. 
\begin{align}
& f(\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda) y_2)-\lambda f(y_1)-(1-\lambda) f(y_2) \\
= & \frac{1}{2}{||\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2-x||}^2-\lambda \bigg{[}\frac{1}{2}{||y_1-x||}^2\bigg{]}-(1-\lambda) \bigg{[}\frac{1}{2}{||y_2-x||}^2\bigg{]}\\
= & \leq \frac{1}{2}\bigg{[}{\lambda}^2{||y_1-x||}^2 +2\lambda(1-\lambda)||y_1-x|| ||y_2-x|| +(1-\lambda)^2 {||y_2-x||}^2\bigg{]} -\lambda \bigg{[}\frac{1}{2}{||y_1-x||}^2\bigg{]}-(1-\lambda) \bigg{[}\frac{1}{2}{||y_2-x||}^2\bigg{]}\\
= & -\frac{1}{2}\lambda(1-\lambda){\bigg{[}||y_1-x||-||y_2-x||\bigg{]}}^2
\end{align}

But I cannot prove that it is $-\frac{1}{2}\lambda(1-\lambda){||y_1-y_2||}^2$ (I have tried the triangle inequality but I find that the inequality side is inverted. Which step is wrong?

Comment: How about taking derivatives instead?

Comment: Note that $f(y) =\tfrac{1}{2}\|y\|_2^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\|x\|_2^2 + \langle x, y \rangle$. The last two terms combined form an affine function of $y$. Thus it is sufficient to prove that $\|y\|_2^2$ is strongly convex, because the sum of a strongly convex function and an affine function remains strongly convex.

Answer (score 3):

The Hessian at any point is the identity matrix, which is of course positive definite. Conclude.

Comment: First, it is to prove "strongly convex" not "convex".
Second, This is not in C^2, so it does not have Hessian matrix when y=x.

Comment: @user295106, a strongly convex function is one that has a positive *definite* Hessian. So your first objection is unfounded. As for your second, that would have been helpful to include *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the factor 1/2 to simplify matters a bit. We want to show that the following is strictly negative when $y_1 \ne y_2$ and $0 < \lambda <1$
$$||\lambda(y_1-x)+(1-\lambda)(y_2-x)||^2 - \lambda||y_1-x||^2 -(1-\lambda)||y_2-x ||^2=$$
 $$-\lambda(1-\lambda)||y_1-x||^2 - \lambda(1-\lambda)||y_2-x||^2+ $$ $$2\lambda(1-\lambda)(y_1-x)\cdot(y_2-x) =   $$
$$-\lambda(1-\lambda)||(y_1-x)-(y_2-x)||^2 =$$
$$-\lambda(1-\lambda)||y_1-y_2||^2 $$

In the interior of the interval between $y_1$ and $y_2$ the factor $\lambda(1-\lambda) >0$. If $y_1 \ne y_2$ then the last expression above must be strictly negative.